# Parse file fscanf

Tags: c, file, parsing, scanf

I want to parse from a file that has the following format (it may change) the number that is after t= (e.g 19625):

```
3a 01 4b 46 7f ff 06 10 42 : crc=42 YES\n
3a 01 4b 46 7f ff 06 10 42 t=19625
```

```
int t;
fp=fopen("text","r");
fscanf(fp,"t=%d",&t);
fclose(fp);
printf("%d\n",t);
```

does not give the output.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Tokenize on white space, `strstr` for `t=` then parse that then `strtol` or something along those lines.

Comment: You wouldn't even have to tokenize it, actually.

Answer (score 1):

modify like this

```
    int t;
    char buff[32];
    FILE *fp=fopen("text","r");
    while(EOF!=fscanf(fp, "%s", buff)){
        if(1==sscanf(buff, "t=%d",&t)){
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d\n",t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, the right keyword is "hexadecimal"

see [How do I read hex numbers into an unsigned int in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396732/how-do-i-read-hex-numbers-into-an-unsigned-int-in-c)

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Try

```
  int readt[4];
  fscanf(fp,"t=%x %x %x %x",&readt[0],&readt[1],&readt[2],&readt[3]);
  t=((256*readt[0]+readt[1])*256+readt[2])*256+readt[3];
  printf("t=%d\n",t);
```

Bye,

Francis

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file doesn't contain a `t` before the `t=`, you could simply replace the

```
fscanf(fp,"t=%d",&t);
```

with

```
fscanf(fp, "%*[^t]t=%d", &t);
```